# JavaScript collection where I can hold a reference to an element

Tags: javascript

Is there, either built-in into the browsers or from a common npm package, a data structure where I can append elements but also hold references to elements through which I can remove elements?

In code:

```
let list = XXX();

list.push(10);
let ref1 = list.push(20);
let ref2 = list.push(30);
list.push(40);

ref1.delete(); // or list.remove(ref1)
ref2.delete(); // or list.remove(ref2)

list.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

would print

```
10
40
```

Comment: Why not an array?

Comment: I assume two reasons: 1) you have to find-and-splice, which is not built-in, 2) if you have `[10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 20, 50]` and want to delete the _second_ `20`, you can't do it (there is nothing in `20` to identify which one it is). The first is trivial, and the second is not an issue if all values are unique, but there's that.

Comment: @vr. What Amadan says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` with `Symbol` keys fits:

```js
class RefMap extends Map {
  push(value) {
    const key = Symbol()
    this.set(key, value)
    return key
  }
}

let list = new RefMap();

list.push(10);
let ref1 = list.push(20);
let ref2 = list.push(30);
list.push(40);

list.delete(ref1)
list.delete(ref2)

list.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Nice. And for anyone wondering, yes, a `Map` preserves order.

Comment: You could also use an object / class instance as the key that can include the `delete()` method from OP's example code ~ https://jsfiddle.net/xpac46fj/

Comment: @Phil Yep. I thought of that, but 1) it needs more memory because the reference needs to remember the map, and 2) OP gave a choice so I took an easier road :P