# How to await something asynchronously

Tags: javascript

This code starts uploads in parallel and removes each from the `uploads` list once it is done.:

```
async function onDrop(files: File[]) {
    for (let f of files) {
        let ref = uploads.push({name: f.name});
        (async () => {
            await api.uploadFile(f, f.name);
            uploads.delete(ref);
        })()
    }
}
```

But I have two issues:

- It has three pairs of parentheses. That's a lot of parentheses.
- PhpStorm complains *Missing await for an async function call* because obviously I'm not waiting for the anonymous function to return.

Can I write this differently so as to avoid both issues?

I want to use `await`, not `.then()`.

Comment: The warning is right - you _don't_ await the promise. If you want to avoid the warning, given you're inside an async function, ...await it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then it would upload one file at a time, which I don't want.

Comment: You should disable that PhpStorm check, since you're using `async` just so you can use `await` instead of `.then()` inside the IIFE. You should be able to disable it locally just for that line, without changing preferences.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The last line is more of a specific feature request than a request for code review. Wouldn't an answer pointing out how to accomplish this specific task be a good fit on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What behaviour _do_ you want? If you want to do them in parallel and still handle the promise you could use Promise.all.

Comment: Typical pattern uses Promise.all and map (last example [here](https://www.samjarman.co.nz/blog/promisedotall)).

Comment: I assume that `uploads` is not just a regular Javascript array? If it is a regular array, there is no `.delete` method on an Array

Comment: @AndrewParks It's the `RefMap` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871825/javascript-collection-where-i-can-hold-a-reference-to-an-element/75872024#75872024).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When performing the map, the function can be async. This avoids an IIFE to trigger the async operation.

```js
async function onDrop(files) {

  await Promise.all(files.map(async f => {
    let ref = uploads.push({name: f.name});
    await api.uploadFile(f, f.name);
    uploads.delete(ref);
  }));
  
}
```

Update: I saw your comment that you want the onDrop function to return without waiting for the files to upload. Therefore, you can do this:

```js
function onDrop(files) {

  files.forEach(async f => {
    let ref = uploads.push({name: f.name});
    await api.uploadFile(f, f.name);
    uploads.delete(ref);
  });

}
```